# Doctrine foreign key constraint

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 two tables XXXX and YYYY. In the first, I have one a foreign key to the second one.

```
create table XXXXXX
(
    id             int   not null,
    yyyyy_id       int   not null,
)

create table YYYYY
(
    id             int   not null,
)
```

So in my Doctrine Entities, I would like represent this relationship with Doctrine Annotation. But, all associations (OneToMany, ManyToOne, ...) required a `targetEntity` parameter.

Is it possible to have a custom field like `$yyyyId` and do the mapping on it?

Maybe like this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="yyyyy_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\@JoinTable(
     *      name="YYYYY",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="yyyyy_id", referencedColumnName="id", fieldName="yyyyyId")}
     * )
     */
    private $yyyyyId;
```

And have an equivalent to:

```
alter table XXXXX
    add constraint fk foreign key (yyyyy_id) references YYYYY (id) on delete cascade;
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do a OneToMany with JoinTable, docs here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Entity for this table if you need to use Doctrine for retrieving data from the joined table. [Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html).

Otherwise, you need to add manually this relation and use [Native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html) for queries

Comment: Incorrect: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Answer (score -1):

could you try this one ?

```
/**
* @ORM/ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\")
*/
private $yyyyyId;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one try that? What makes you think that this solves the problem? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer